# Find odd in given list (-6 through 38), then put odds in an array

Tags: java

Here is my code so far. There is some redundancy as i was trying to make sure nothing jumbles up, though i doubted it would, just was being more safe than sorry i suppose.

```
  int[] odds=new int[22]; // array to hold values
  odds[0]=-5; // couldn't figure out how to make these work, so i manually
  odds[1]=-3; // input them, help on that would be appreciated as well

  for (int count=0; count<39; count++)
  {
     int temp=0;

     if ((count%2)==0) // i have put the array in the odd part as well with
     {                 // same result
        int index=2;
        odds[index]=temp-1; // turns the even odd by subtracting 1
        index++;
     }
     temp++;
  }
```

I compiled it, got no errors, upon running it says it cannot run. no infinite run, just flat out cannot run. exact words are "Complation failed, but no error lines were detected. Check for non-clickable errors in compile output". checked the non clickable part and nothing.

I use Jgrasp as my IDE, and the website that checks my answers cant get past the 4th index in my array (it just puts 0's till last arrays index). Help would be most appreciated because this is boggling my mind. tried other methods but to no avail.

Comment: Unrelated to the problems you might be facing, you should move `int temp = 0` and `int index=2;` lines outside `for` loop. Right now it is always getting initialized with 0 and 2 respectively and ending up overwriting the value of `odds[2]`.

Comment: Done, same result in JGrasp, weird, the website takes it. thanks. funny how did i overlook that.

Comment: It runs just fine for me. Here is the output of `odds` Array: `-5
-3
-1
1
3
5
7
9
11
13
15
17
19
21
23
25
27
29
31
33
35
37`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A cleaner implementation:

```
ArrayList<int> odds = new ArrayList<int>();

for (int number = -6; number <= 38; number++) {
    if(number % 2 == 1)
        odds.add(number);
}
```

If you need to use an `int[]` type array, then you will need to add the logic to keep track of the index, etc.

```
int[] odds = new int[22];
int index = 0;

for (int number = -6; number <= 38; number++) {
    if(Math.abs(number) % 2 == 1) {
        odds[index] = number;
        index++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help as well. I need to remember about math.abs too. lol. much appreciated for the cleaner look too.

Answer (score 0):

Credit goes to https://stackoverflow.com/users/2004685/user2004685 for helping me answer. goes to show easy to overlook the little stuff. much thanks.

```
  int[] odds=new int[22];
  odds[0]=-5;
  odds[1]=-3;

  int temp=0;
  int index=2;
  for (int count=0; count<39; count++)
  {


     if ((count%2)==0)
     {

        odds[index]=temp-1;
        index++;
     }
     temp++;
  }
```